# jruby activerecord attempting to save binary data in ms sql causes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, jruby

I'm using
 sql server 2008
 jruby on rails 3.2.7
 jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.9.2-p312)

The following table

```
create_table "Users", :primary_key => "id" do |t|
  t.integer "id", :limit => 19, :default => 1, :null => false
  t.string "login", :limit => 80, :null => false
  t.binary "password"
end
```

When I populate the table with data I can pull back records with no problem. when I try to save I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: @user.save!
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.: INSERT INTO [Users] ( [login], [password]) VALUES ( N'user', '')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this

```
t.binary "password"
```

and this

```
INSERT INTO [Users] ( [login], [password]) VALUES ( N'user', '')
```

the `INSERT` statement has a string for the password, when the field is defined as binary.

In SQL Server, these two types are not compatible. Binary values are specified as `0x<bytes>`, i.e., `0xAABBCCDD`.

Either you need to convert the password value that's being passed to the `INSERT` statement into that kind of format (perhaps byte-array output from a hashing function), or change the table column type to be a string.